# Missing purchased tab in App Store and Family Sharing in iOS 11

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, family-sharing

How can I get access to family purchased apps in iOS 11? The new version of the App Store has no purchased tab where I can select the family member in top left corner and get access to download app without payment from my Apple ID. iBooks and iTunes Store have this tab.

Comment: you can't have restrictions on the iPads in order to see the account

Comment: On any of the tabs but search, you should see your account photo in the upper right hand corner. After you tap your account icon, you will see a 'Purchased' menu row in the second group from the top. Inside the Purchased menu, you will see yourself at the top and any of your family members underneath. Notice: you may need to be on wifi for your family's purchases to load. When on cellular data, we noticed family member's accounts showed no purchases. I will submit this as an answer to the question instead of a comment as soon as soon as I have the reputation to do so.

Answer (score 5):

In the Today tab, tap the account icon in the top right, then choose Purchased.

Comment: But there no option to select family member tab

Comment: Don’t forget to file bug report with Apple  and check on beta site for known issues @user3812375. I can’t imagine that iOS 11 is even feature complete yet let alone not swimming in bugs.

Comment: I have the family memembers, but most of them show no purchases, better submit a bug report

Answer (score 2):

You can search the app you want to download and choose to purchase. After you give your password the new appstore gives the message that someone else in your family already paid for it and you can download it for free.

This is confirmed by myself just now after i read about it on the developers forum at apple beta.